# Run sequental graphql queries using Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am trying to load data using below queries in `React`.

```
export const GET_POSTS = gql`
    query GetLaunches($limit: Int) {
        launches(limit: $limit) {
            name
            id
            date_utc
        }
    }
`;
```

I am using above query like below inside React component.

```
const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(GET_POSTS, {
        variables: { limit },
        skip: !limit
    });
```

Above return data like below.

```
data = {
  items: [
    {
      date_utc: "2014-01-06T18:06:00.000Z"
      id: ['9D1B7E0']
      name: "Thaicom 6"
    },
{
      date_utc: "2014-01-06T18:06:00.000Z"
      id: ['1S1B5D0']
      name: "Thai 0"
    },
    {
      date_utc: "2014-01-06T18:06:00.000Z"
      id: ['7F1B7E3']
      name: "Sun 6"
    },
{
      date_utc: "2014-01-06T18:06:00.000Z"
      id: ['4A1B5K7']
      name: "Moon 0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now what I want to make another query where I will pass above `id` as a variable to another query and load description of each individual above list of items.

I tried below. Below is queries.ts file.

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

export const GET_POSTS = gql`
    query GetLaunches($limit: Int) {
        launches(limit: $limit) {
            name
            id
            date_utc
        }
    }
`;

export const GET_DESCRIPTION = gql`
    query GetDescription($id: ID!) {
        mission(id: $id) {
        description
      }
    }
`;
```

Here is Home.tsx file.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { HomeContainer } from '../Container/';
import { GET_POSTS, GET_DESCRIPTION } from '../Queries/';

export const Home: React.FC = () => {
    const limit = 10;
    const launches = useQuery(GET_LAUNCHES, {
        variables: { limit },
        skip: !limit
    });

    const launchDescription = useQuery(GET_DESCRIPTION, {
        variables: { id: launches?.data?.launches?.mission_id?.[0] },
        skip: launches.loading || !launches?.data?.launches?.mission_id?.[0],
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(launchDescription.data); // returns undefined
        console.log(launches.data); // this returns correct data
    }, [launches]);

    return (
        <HomeContainer
            loading={launches.loading}
            error={launches.error}
            data={launches.data}
        />
    );
}
```

Inside `useEffect` hook, I want to add description to each individual launch in `launches.data` array. How can I make this work?

Comment: Your second query needs to wait on the first query's result before it runs. To control when a query runs, use `useLazyQuery` instead of `useQuery`: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#uselazyquery

Comment: @PierreLejay the problem is that how can I get the ID from `GET_POSTS` query and pass that as a variable to `useLazyQuery`. I am using this `{ variables: { id: launches.data.launches.id?.[0] } }` but it is returning this error `message: "Variable \"$id\" of required type \"ID!\" was not provided."`.

Comment: That is why you need the useEffect. There is nothing in `useQuery` or `useLazyQuery` as used here that makes the query wait for your id to be available; you need a function that polls whether the data exists asynchronously, which is what useEffect can be used for. See my answer for implementation

Answer (score 0):

You need to use optional chaining for `launches?.loading` or simply just omit this to `!launches?.data?.launches?.mission_id?.[0]`

Comment: That doesn't help with the fact that both queries are fired at the same time. The id will still be undefined because the second query is not made to wait until the first one is completed. That is why `useLazyQuery` is needed

Answer (score 0):

Both of your queries right now are fired at the same time. What you need to do is make the second query wait for the first one to be completed (using `useLazyQuery`), and only fire when the ID is available.

Here is how that should look:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useQuery, useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { HomeContainer } from '../Container/';
import { GET_POSTS, GET_DESCRIPTION } from '../Queries/';

export const Home: React.FC = () => {
    const limit = 10;
    const launches = useQuery(GET_POSTS, {
        variables: { limit },
        skip: !limit
    });

  // useLazyQuery provides a function you can use to fire the query
  // only when you have what you need for it
  const [getLaunchDescription, launchDescription] = useLazyQuery(GET_DESCRIPTION)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // check that you have the id before you ask for the description 
    if (launches?.data?.launches?.mission_id?.length) {
      getLaunchDescription({
        variables: { id: launches.data.launches.mission_id[0] }
      });
    }
  }, [launches])

    return (
        <HomeContainer
            loading={launches.loading}
            error={launches.error}
            data={launches.data}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: The problem remains there as `launches.data` is an array of object with `mission_id` to those objects' properties. How can I loop through that and make that GraphQL request happen.

Comment: You could loop through `launches.data` using `forEach` running `getLaunchDescription` each time with each id and have another `useEffect` keeping track of the value of `launchDescription` and appending each new value to an array saved in `useState`.
This is not a good practice though, you don't want to flood the network with tons of queries. The correct way would be to extend your `GET_DESCRIPTION` resolver to accept an array of ids instead of just a single id

Comment: Could you provide an example of the later one i.e. making this work with resolver you mentioned? Thanks

Comment: I could not answer that without more details about your backend, and that goes beyond the scope of this question. I would advise you try it yourself first, and if you get stuck submit a new question detailing what you tried and where you got stuck. This is a common use case so you should also be able to find examples online and in the documentation of whatever backend tools you are using